# Jquery Toggle not Working with a sibiling div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

I have been scratching my head for hours over this. This code is supposed to make a div visible but it's not working.

```
<div id="butbr">
  <div id="sup_nav">
    <div id="stup" class="bxt1"></div>
    <div id="exep" class="bxt1"></div>
    <div id="trat" class="bxt1"></div>
    <div id="tstm" class="bxt2"></div>
    <div id="whys" class="bxt3"></div>
    <div id="regu" class="bxt3"></div>
  </div>
  <a id="btn_sup" href="">
    <div id="top_nav">
      <img src="../images/logos/mcwb.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

JS (I'm thinking the error is somewhere in here, but the console doesn't show any errors):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn_sup").click(function(event) {
    $("#sup_nav").show();
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
#butbr {
    background-color: #FFF;
    max-width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    min-width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    /*box-shadow: 0px 3px 12px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.58);*/
    box-shadow:0px 2px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
}

#btn_sup {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 5;
}

#sup_nav {
    width: 75%;
    height: 525px;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Just found out : click on the link 3 - 4 times on a row made it just apper and dis apear ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are clicking on a anchor tab which is reloading the page, stop the default action

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#btn_sup").click(function (e) {
        $("#sup_nav").show();
        e.preventDefault()
    });
});
```